# How to use AntiXSS library in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

I've upgraded an application from **Asp.Net 3.5** to **Asp.Net 4.5**. I've seen many post about the merit of using AntiXSS library. I didn't see so far any telling how to use it.

It's suggested to enabled it in the web.config like this:

```
<httpRuntime ... 
      encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, 
      Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I'd like to know whether enabling the library in the web.config is the only thing I need to do or should also **encode** input values from **TextBoxes**?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

Let's say, I have a textbox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Should I encode the input in the code-behind:

```
string value = SomeEncodeMethod(TextBox1.Text)
```

Do I need to do this?

Comment: I am kind of in a similar boat, seems http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx/ is the best I could find

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems like Phil Haack just created the class but I didn't see where he encoded any value coming from an input control. I don't know whether I should assume that the only thing to do is to enable the library in the web.config because it's part of the asp.net framework now.

Comment: Spin up a simple POC, the configuration you did should work. I will try it myself when I get back to this task. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Razor in .NET MVC (and also the `<%:` tag in aspx) encodes values automatically to an html context. This means that when you do `@myVar` in cshtml with Razor, any `<` will become `&lt;`, `"` will become `&quote;` and so on. But by default it uses a blacklist and only encodes a few characters, leaves everything else alone.

If you switch to AntiXSS as described in your question, this default encoder is changed to AntiXSS. The main benefit is that AntiXSS is a whitelist encoder, it has a list of a few characters that are ok to be left alone (letters and numbers, mainly), and everything else is encoded. This is slightly more secure and might prevent some attacks that would otherwise be possible.

You need to be aware though that this encoding is not always enough. To prevent XSS, you need to choose the right encoding for the right context. For an html context (and also for html attribute values, mostly), the default encoding is ok. However, it is *not* ok for a Javascript context. For instance this is vulnerable to XSS in a cshtml with either the default or the AntiXss html encoder:

```
<script>
    var myVar=@myVar;
</script>
```

To make this secure, you need to encode it to a Javascript context with `JavaScriptEncode()` in AntiXss **and** put it between quotes (`'`). Note that without the quotes, it's still vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: Hey @Gabor Lengyel. Thank you for the insight. So bottom line, what you are suggesting is to still encode the value of the textbox in aspx file. This is mostly my concern. Please look at the Edit.

Comment: Ah ok. You don't need further encoding, asp:TextBox takes care of that by default. You can try this by entering things like `<script>` into the textbox (even with request validation turned off, which is an additional line of defense in additon to output encoding).

Answer (score 1):

**How to use AntiXSS library in our projct.**

Firstly we need to download AntiXss 4.2.1.msi from this location

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589

and install it and then copy the AntiXSSLibrary.dll from below loaction(It will be stored after installation) and then we can use it in our project.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Information Security\AntiXSS Library v4.2\NET40